# Making .animate a function

Tags: jquery

Trying to make the jquery .animate into a function so it would take up less space and be easier for me to read

```
function anim(object, values, end) { // Problem with the "end" part
    $(object).animate (values, {
        duration: 1000,
        quene: false,
        specialEasing: {top: "easeOutQuad"},
        complete: function() end // <-- here
    })
})
```

I tried making it like {end} too but it would work. Also tried changing end to a different name but didn't work still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to pass in a function that represents your `complete` event when you call it. So your `anim()` function should look like the following :

```
// The end parameter is simply a function that will be mapped to your completion event
function anim(object, values, end) { 
    $(object).animate (values, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false,
        specialEasing: {top: "easeOutQuad"},
        // This will map the completion event to your function that was
        // passed in
        complete: end 
    })
}
```

To actually call the function, you would simply need to pass in the selector to target the element, a series of values

```
anim('#your-element', { ... }, function(){ alert('Done!'); });
```

Comment: Oh ok I thought it would accept it automatically if I inputted a table but I guess not